# how to count number of occurence of a specific time value in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataset named transaction having 350241 observations.

Sample of the data:

```
transaction_id    timestamp              product_code 
19241             2001-01-11 15:48:00     1
29247             2001-04-08 11:25:00     9
34567             2001-03-10 16:24:00     17
48790             2001-09-23 13:33:00     45
56789             2001-11-01 11:47:00     52
```

**QUESTION**

How many transactions were carried out during 18:00 hour?
How can I find this using R?
I tried with tables but the dataset is big so it isn't showing up all the frequency counts.

Comment: Please provide reproducible input (perhaps with `dput`), and expected output

Comment: Welcome to *Stack Overflow*, in order that we can help you best, please provide example data and the steps you've tried so far. Consider [*How to make a great reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), thanks.

Comment: Post dput( head( data_object, 20)) and show what codding efforts you have attempted so far. Otherwise this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create an `hour` variable using `lubridate::hour(timestamp)`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  count(hour = hour(timestamp))
```

You can then filter for just hour 18:

```
df %>%
  count(hour = hour(timestamp)) %>%
  filter(hour == 18)
```

A more verbose way of accomplishing the same thing:

```
df %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  tally() %>%
  filter(hour == 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, convert the 'timestamp' to `POSIXlt`, extract the `hour`, convert it to logical vector (`==`) and get the `sum` of TRUE elements

```
sum(as.POSIXlt(df1$timestamp)$hour == 18)
```